# how to get the count of particular object in a List?

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to get the count of the particular object in List

```
AgentSumBeans obj=new AgentSumBeans();
            while(rs.next())
            {

                obj.setIrctcIdCreatedDate(rs.getString(1)); 
                obj.setIsevaProOpted(rs.getString(2));

            }
          list.add(obj);// first object

AgentSumBeans obj2=null;
            while(rs3.next())
            { 
                obj2=new AgentSumBeans();
            obj2.setAmonthyear(rs3.getString(1));
            obj2.setAnoOfTkts(rs3.getInt(2));
            obj2.setAbookingAmount(rs3.getInt(3));
            obj2.setAavgAmount(rs3.getInt(4));
            obj2.setAperDayTkts(rs3.getInt(5));

            list.add(obj2);// i will be getting more than one object here

            }
```

how to find how many `obj2` objects got created ?

Comment: list.size() - 1?

Comment: or did you mean with a specific value? iterate over the list, and use the equals to verify. you can add a counter in the code easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `while` loop to `for` loop with counter - and it's the simplest solution, i think.

Or create counter before `while` loop.

Comment: yeah i did that , But is there any way means method to find count of particular object in a list?

Comment: @bharathRaj yes, read my comment, I explained there what it takes to do that